# Testing asynchronous methods on iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing, asynchronous

I tried OCUnit, GTM, and iUnitTest but none of them supports testing for asynchronous methods.
How do you test asynchronous methods on iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making a local runloop in the test case?

Here you can have the test case wait for completion of the asynchronous call and possibly perform some timout checks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this answer to a different stackoverflow question: [Testing asynchronous code on iOS with OCunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685582/testing-asynchronous-code-on-ios-with-ocunit/4784263#4784263)