# Testing asynchronous code on iOS with OCunit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Does anyone know of any existing library that allows testing asynchronous code with OCUnit?
I'm thinking about something like `GHAsyncTestCase` but that delivers from `SenTestCase`.

I'm asking because if I don't find any I'm going to port `GHAsyncTestCase` to OCUnit but I don't want to duplicate work done already by someone else.

Comment: I don't know of anyone doing this before but I have to ask; why do you feel the need to test asynchronous behavior in a framework normally used to run unit tests? Do you not trust the two halves of your behavior? Can you not test them separately? Are you really writing integration tests?

Comment: @Jonah, You are right it is really useful but sometimes I'm too lazy to mock up the whole Network Layer. Then it is really tempting to just run a local server and integration tests against it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Piotr:

You might be interested in the work I've done with [Mimic](http://github.com/lukeredpath/mimic), a network stubbing tool written in Ruby which lets you stub requests at a high-level and can be used from your Objective-C using the supplied wrapper.

With regards to asynchronous testing, please take a look at a little utility I wrote called [AssertEventually](https://gist.github.com/506353/).

[This example](https://gist.github.com/784929) shows both Mimic and assertEventually in action.

In addition, you might want to look at [Kiwi](http://www.kiwi-lib.info/) - it's a great little Objective-C testing framework that is built on top of OCUnit. I recently contributed a patch to port my AssertEventually behaviour over to Kiwi which lets you write things like:

```
id someObject = nil;
[do SomethingThatFetchesSomeObjectAsynchronously];
[[theObject(&someObject) shouldEventually] equal:@"some result"];
```

Comment: It is something that I was looking for. Mimic looks quite interesting I will have a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: AssertEventually sounds handy, but the link is dead.  Any help?

Comment: I'm using Kiwi with the `-shouldEventually` behavior; fancy to find that it was your handiwork. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[AGAsyncTestHelper](https://github.com/hfossli/AGAsyncTestHelper) takes a slightly different approach than `AssertEventually` since it is evaluating the expression rather than checking the pointer for new results. One advantage of using [AGAsyncTestHelper](https://github.com/hfossli/AGAsyncTestHelper) is that it can be used for blocks, delegate-callbacks and whatnot.

```
WAIT_WHILE(<expression_to_evaluate>, <max_duration>);
```

Answering the question

```
id someObject = nil;
[self doSomethingThatFetchesSomeObjectAsynchronously];
WAIT_WHILE(self.someObject == nil, 1.0);
```