# Delayed OCMock verify / Dealing with Timeout in Unit Tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, asynchronous, timeout, ocmock

I'm testing real web service calls with OCMock.

Right now I'm doing *something* like:

```
- (void)testWebservice
{
    id mydelegatemock = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(MySUTDelegate)];
    [[mydelegatemock expect] someMethod:[OCMArg any]];

    [SUT sutWithDelegate:mydelegatemock];

    // we need to wait for real result
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2.0]];

    [(OCMockObject*)mydelegatemock verify];
}
```

It works fine, but it implies that every such test will take 2 seconds.

Is there a way I can set a timeout of e.g. 2 seconds, and let a call to `someMethod` of `mydelegatemock` immediately `verify` and complete the test case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do this using a handy utility function I found [at this link](http://touchalicious.com/blog/2009/11/5/asynchronous-unit-testing-with-ocmock.html):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>

@interface TestUtils : NSObject
+ (void)waitForVerifiedMock:(OCMockObject *)mock delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "TestUtils.h"
@implementation TestUtils

+ (void)waitForVerifiedMock:(OCMockObject *)inMock delay:(NSTimeInterval)inDelay
{
    NSTimeInterval i = 0;
    while (i < inDelay)
    {
        @try
        {
            [inMock verify];
            return;
        }
        @catch (NSException *e) {}
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
        i+=0.5;
    }
    [inMock verify];
}

@end
```

This allows me to to wait up to a maximum delay (in seconds) without waiting the full amount each time.

Comment: Perhaps originated here?... http://touchalicious.com/blog/2009/11/5/asynchronous-unit-testing-with-ocmock.html

Comment: Thanks Max - that looks like the source. I've updated the original response with a link to the original.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the functional testing of your web services (if you need to do that at all) from the unit testing of your class that processes the web service result.

To unit test, you should mock the web service call, providing a mock result. Then your test would verify that, for that well-defined result, your class behaves accordingly.

If you also want to do functional testing of your web service (say that it returns a specific response given some request), you don't need to mock anything--just call the service and make assertions on the result.

By separating out your tests, you have finer control over the test runs. For example, you could run your fast-running unit tests every time you change code, but run your slow-running functional tests nightly, on a dedicated server, or as needed. And when a test breaks, you'll know whether it's your code or something wrong with the web service.

Comment: I already have canned tests with immediate fake returns from the web service. This question was about integration tests with the real web service. I admit that I could leave the application part aside in those, but it does not change the fact that I need to wait for the result somehow. And: with the canned results, I don't test having a latency between request and result, as with canned results, the result delegate actually is called *before* the request call is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could also switch to GHUnit, like a fellow member suggests in the answer to this related question:

[SenTestingKit in Xcode 4: Asynchronous testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190486/sentestingkit-in-xcode-4-asynchronous-testing)

You can find GHUnit here

https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit